# Vue mapping or filtering array based on UI selections,

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have JSON data hundreds of entries like this:

```
{
"product":"Protec",
"type":"Central Opening",
"attribute":"Triple Lock",
"height":"2100",
"width":"1600",
 "price":"3000"
},
{
"product":"Protec",
"type":"Sliding Door",
"attribute":"Single Lock",
"height":"2100",
"width":"1600",
"price":"3000"
},
{
"product":"ForceField",
"type":"Hinge Door",
"attribute":"Triple Lock",
"height":"2300",
"width":"1200",
"price":"100"
},
```

my vue component

```
var distinct_product = new Vue({
    el: '#distinct',
    data:{
      distinct_product: [],
      all_products: []
    },
```

I fetch it and store it in my vue component and store it in a second data so when I render it to the ui the user only sees distinct elements.

```
 mounted: async function(){
      fetch("/Data/products.json")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => { 
          this.all_products = res
          this.distinct_product = res

          var disProduct = [...new Set(this.distinct_product.map(x => x.product))]
          var disType = [...new Set(this.distinct_product.map(x => x.type))]
          var disAttribute = [...new Set(this.distinct_product.map(x => x.attribute))]

          this.distinct_product.productArray = disProduct;
          this.distinct_product.typeArray = disType;
          this.distinct_product.attributeArray = disAttribute;
```

My problem is, it also renders elements that aren't available to certain products.

for example a `product : 'Window'` can't have the `attribute : 'triple locks'`

I was wondering if I could filter/map the all_products array as the user selects a product.

I looked into computed properties mainly but I'm not sure of a good way to do it. this is my first attempt at a web app and I'm fairly new to JS too.

I aimed to iterate through the array pushing only objects containing the product selected in the UI
atm this is what I've attempted with no luck:
`this.distinct_product.product` which is bound to the UI

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.all_products.length; i++){
  if (this.all_products[i] === this.distinct_product.product){
    this.product.push(i);
    return this.product;
 }
}
```

so it would iterate over `all_products` looking for objects containing `this.distinct_product.product` which would contain 'Protec' or another product

Am I going at this the wrong way? should I step back in general and try and work with that data a different way?

Sorry if the question is structured poorly it's a skill I'm trying to work on, criticism is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. I'll share a simple example so you can understand and make changes to your code accordingly.

```js
var productdata = [
        {
            "product": "Protec",
            "type": "Central Opening",
            "attribute": "Triple Lock",
            "height": "2100",
            "width": "1600",
            "price": "3000"
        },
        {
            "product": "Protec",
            "type": "Sliding Door",
            "attribute": "Single Lock",
            "height": "2100",
            "width": "1600",
            "price": "3000"
        },
        {
            "product": "ForceField",
            "type": "Hinge Door",
            "attribute": "Triple Lock",
            "height": "2300",
            "width": "1200",
            "price": "100"
        },
    ];
    //setTimeout(function () {
    distinct_productVue = new Vue({
        el: '#distinct',
        data: {
            //selected: {},
            distinct_products: [],
            all_products: productdata.map(function (x, index) {
                return { text: x.product, value: index + 1 };
            }),
            selected: '0'
        },
        computed: {
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.all_products.unshift({ text: 'Please select a product', value: 0 });
        },
        methods: {
            getDistinctProduct: function () {
                var self = this;
                self.distinct_products = productdata.filter(function (x, index) {
                    if (x.product === self.all_products[self.selected].text) {
                        return { text: x.product, value: index };
                    }
                    else { return false; }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.0/vue.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="distinct">
        <select v-model="selected" v-on:change="getDistinctProduct">
            <option v-for="option in all_products" v-bind:value="option.value">
                {{ option.text }}
            </option>
        </select>
        <!--<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>-->
        <div v-show="selected != 0" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <b>Available products</b>
            <div v-for="pro in distinct_products" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <div>product: {{pro.product}}</div>
                <div>type: {{pro.type}}</div>
                <div>attribute: {{pro.attribute}}</div>
                <div>height: {{pro.height}}</div>
                <div>width: {{pro.width}}</div>
                <div>price: {{pro.price}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```